# How can I Join customer records in SQL Server to show missing transaction types

Tags: t-sql, join, set-difference

I have two simple tables comprised of CustomerNumber, TransactionNumber and AddonCode in each.

The first table contains only TransactionNumber of 1 [Orig_DD]. This represents us transferring a customer from one system to another.

The second table contains all the transaction numbers per customer number that are higher than 1 [Later_Lines_DD]. These represent add-ons purchased after their record has been transferred to the new system.

I need to show customer records where;

The add-on code/s that were present in TransactionNumber 1 do not show against the subsequent TransactionNumbers on the customer's record.

Currently I have them LEFT joined together like so and I've hit a wall;

```
SELECT  cd1.CustomerNumber,
    cd1.TransactionNumber,
    cd1.AddonCode,
    cdg1.CustomerNumber,
    cdg1.TransactionNumber,
    cdg1.AddonCode
FROM Orig_DD cd1 LEFT JOIN LaterLines_DD cdg1  ON cd1.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber
                                                        AND cd1.AddonCode = cdg1.AddonCode 
ORDER BY cd1.CustomerNumber, cdg1.AddonCode
```

Examples of the issues caused by joining on CustomerNumber & AddonCode that I can't figure out;

1: If a customer's add-on codes are in later transaction numbers AND the 1st transaction, they need to be excluded (column headers abbreviated to fit)

```
CustNo  TransNo AddonCode   CustNo  TransNo AddonCode
2490    1       Z1          2490    2       Z1
2490    1       Z2          2490    2       Z2
```

2. If a customer's add-ons from TransactionNumber 1 don't appear in later transactions, the join conditions fail and NULLs appear to the right. 
   This is the main issue - I need to return all transaction numbers on the right where the customer's add-ons from TransactionNumber 1 don't appear again;

`CustNo  TransNo    AddonCode   CustNo  TransNo   AddonCode`

```
2497    1         Z1            NULL    NULL      NULL
2497    1         Z2            NULL    NULL      NULL
```

Instead of the above, I need to see the following;

```
CustNo    TransNo    AddonCode    CustNo    TransNo    AddonCode
2497      1          Z1           2497      2          ZE
2497      1          Z2           2497      2          ZQ
```

If I remove the AddonCode from the join, the CustomerNumber on it's own creates every permeation of CustomerNumber, TransactionNumber and AddonCode leaving me with no gaps to indicate where an addon code didn't carry across to a higher transaction number.

I can't think how I can join my two tables together to exclude example 1 and keep the data but as I need to see it in the second part of example 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this using `Inner Join` , `Corelated Subquery` and `NOT IN` function.

```
SELECT  cd1.CustomerNumber,
    cd1.TransactionNumber,
    cd1.AddonCode,
    cdg1.CustomerNumber,
    cdg1.TransactionNumber,
    cdg1.AddonCode
FROM       Orig_DD cd1 
inner JOIN LaterLines_DD cdg1  ON cd1.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber
where cd1.AddonCode  not in 
( select  AddonCode
  from    LaterLines_DD Ldd
  where   Ldd.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber  
  AND     Ldd.AddonCode = cd1.AddonCode  
)
ORDER BY cd1.CustomerNumber, cdg1.AddonCode
```

In the Above query, Using `Corelated subquery` you can find the records which has same `AddonCode` in both the table for each customer. Then you can exclude this using `not in` function.

```
where cd1.AddonCode  not in 
( select  AddonCode
  from    LaterLines_DD Ldd
  where   Ldd.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber  
  AND     Ldd.AddonCode = cd1.AddonCode  
)
```

Use `Inner join` and join them only on `CustomerNumber` you will get the record having different `Addon` for each customer.

```
inner JOIN LaterLines_DD cdg1  ON cd1.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT  cd1.CustomerNumber,
    cd1.TransactionNumber,
    cd1.AddonCode,
    cdg1.CustomerNumber,
    cdg1.TransactionNumber,
    cdg1.AddonCode
FROM Orig_DD cd1 INNER JOIN LaterLines_DD cdg1  ON cd1.CustomerNumber = cdg1.CustomerNumber AND cd1.TransactionNumber = (cdg1.TransactionNumber +1)
ORDER BY cd1.CustomerNumber, cdg1.AddonCode;
```